# Minecraft scoreboard operation by number

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft Java 1.18.1 I want to operate two scoreboard with a number like:

```
scoreboard players operation @p lives = (@p deaths - 3)
```

But this command is not working, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

`scoreboard players operation @p lives -= @p 3c`
You need an extra objective which is a constant to do this because scoreboard operations only support scoreboard objectives, in other words, you can't utilize integers in subtraction.

```
scoreboard objectives add 3c dummy
scoreboard players set @a 3c 3
```

Hope this helps.